# Passing List<Domain Object> to a Method Expecting List<object>

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I know I'm missing something fundamental with either generics or covariance, and I was hoping there is a better way to do what I am doing.

I have a method that takes a list of domain objects and turns it into an HTML table:

```
public String GenerateTable(List<object> Data, String[] Properties,
    String[] ColumnHeaders = null)
{
}
```

When I call the method, I find myself having to do this:

```
List<Customer> cust = GetCustomers();
List<object> oCust = new List<object>;
foreach (Customer c in cust)
    oCust.Add((object)c);

string table = GenerateTable(oCust, new string[] { "CustNbr", "CustName" });
```

I believe with covariance I can simply:

```
List<object> oCust = cust;
```

But I'm looking for a better solution all-around -- eliminate the necessity to create a completely new list each time I run this method.  It's not a performance or memory issue, as these lists are always relatively small, but I'd like to understand what is the best (or at least better) way to accomplish this.

Comment: Does `GenerateTable` add or remove anything from the list?  If not, `IEnumerable<object>` or even just `IEnumerable` would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change GenerateTable to accept an IEnumerable of objects instead of a list. Then you won't have to convert your Customer list to a list of objects.

```
public String GenerateTable(IEnumerable<object> Data, String[] Properties, String[] ColumnHeaders = null)
```

The problem with your original version is that GenerateTable could attempt to add a non-Customer object to the List. IEnumerable works because it is read only. You can read more about it [here](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2009/02/what-c-40-covariance-doesn-do.html), if you are interested.

Comment: Great explanation...  it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

Covariance is only supported in generic interfaces.   Since it looks like an `IEnumerable` would be sufficient you can try to not use a generic at all.

```
public string GenerateTable(IEnumerable data, string[] properties, string[] columnHeaders = null)
```

Alternately, you could set up a generic transformation method

```
public string GenerateRow(Customer customer) { // convert one object here} 

public string GenerateTable<T>(List<T> objects, Func<T,string> rowGenerator) 
{
   // table boilerplate
   foreach(var obj in objects) {
     output.Append(rowGenerate(customer)) 
   }
}
```

and then call it with

```
var table = GenerateTable(customerList, GenerateRow);
```

to generate your table.